# how to use enum with decision making switch statements

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement

i'm working on a little calculator and i don't know how to use enum with the switch/case so what i need to dont make this working
i only need to scan a number and than see what the he wants with enum
dont refer to comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.141592
int hypotri(void);
int disBePoints(void);
int circle(int y);
int square(void);
typedef enum calcOption
{
distance=1,
hypotenuse=2,
areaC=3,
areaR=4,
areaS=5
}option;


int main(void)
{
float finish=0, y=0,i=0;
printf("Welcome to my calculator!\n");
while(i!=6)
{
printf("Welcome to my calculator!\nchoose option:\n1 - Calc distance between        2 points\n2 - Calc hypotenuse of triangle\n3 - Calc area and perimeter of circle\n4 - Calc area of rectangle\n5 - Calc area of square\n6 - Exit");
scanf("%d",&option);
calcOption option;
option=calcOPtion(i);
switch(option)
{
    case distance:
    {
        disBePoints();
        ("the distance is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    case hypotenuse:
    {
        hypotri();
        ("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    case areaC:
    {
        for(y=1;y>2;y++)
        {
            circle(y);
            if(y=1)
            {
                ("the perimeter is %f",finish);
            }
            else
            {
                ("the area is %f",finish);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    case areaR:
    {
        square();
        ("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    case areaS:
    {
        square();
        ("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        printf("dont mess with me enter number between 1-6");
    }
}
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
/** why= to see what is the distance between any points\n
input=none
output=none
**/
int disBePoints(void)
{
float xOne=0,xTwo=0,yOne=0,yTwo=0, finish=0;
printf("Enter point 1 coordinates:");
scanf("%f%f",&xOne,&yOne);
printf("\nEnter point 2 coordinates:");
scanf("%f%f",&xTwo,&yTwo);
finish=sqrt(pow(xTwo-xOne,2)+pow(yTwo-yOne,2));
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is the hypotenuse of the triange
input=none
output=none
**/
int hypotri(void)
{
float x=0,y=0,finish;
printf("Enter 2 sides of the triangle:");
scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);
finish=sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2));
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is primeter and the area of the circle
input=none
output=none
**/
int circle(int y)
{
float radius=0,finish=0;
printf("Enter circle radius:");
scanf("%f",&radius);
if(y=1)
{
    finish=radius*2*Pi;
}
else
{
    finish=pow(radius,2)*Pi;
}
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is  the area of the rectangle or the square
input=none
output=none
**/
int square(void)
{
float yside=0,xside=0,finish=0;
printf("Enter  lentgh and width:");
scanf("%f%f",&xside,&yside);
finish=yside*xside;
return finish;
}
```

Comment: You define `option` to be a *type name*, it is used as a type and not a variable.

Comment: Mind asking a question after reading what makes a [mcve]?

Comment: You should explain a bit better what the problem is. What's NOT working?

Comment: Your compiler doesn't emit any diagnostic when it sees `calcOption option;`? You are compiling your code as `c++`. Switch to `c` and you'll get a helpful warning.

Comment: Start indenting youir code properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you typedef calcOption like:

```
typedef enum calcOption
{
distance=1,
hypotenuse=2,
areaC=3,
areaR=4,
areaS=5
}option;
```

The option after the last brace is a type, you've said "let option have the same meaning as calcOption. It's not an object. So later in main() when you do:

```
scanf("%d", &option);
```

It doesn't make sense because with the ampersand you're giving the address of a type, not an object.

I got a feeling you understand this, because you typedeffed "calcOption" as "object", and then you created "object" object:

```
calcOptions options;
// Is the same as:
option option
// Though very confusing as you've got the same name.
```

If you switch around two lines like this:

```
calcOption option;
scanf("%d", &option);
```

That would be right, but you have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected the enum part and the infinite loop**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.141592
int hypotri(void);
int disBePoints(void);
int circle(int y);
int square(void);
enum calcOption
{
distance=1,
hypotenuse=2,
areaC=3,
areaR=4,
areaS=5
};


int main(void)
{
 int i=0;
float finish=0, y=0;
printf("Welcome to my calculator!\n");
while(i<1 || i>5 )
{
printf("Welcome to my calculator!\nchoose option:\n1 - Calc distance between 2 points\n2 - Calc hypotenuse of triangle\n3 - Calc area and perimeter of circle\n4 - Calc area of rectangle\n5 - Calc area of square\n6 - Exit");
scanf("%d",&i);
//calcOption option;
//option=calcOption(i);
switch(i)
{
    case distance: disBePoints();
                   printf("the distance is %f",finish);
                   break;

    case hypotenuse: hypotri();
                     printf("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
                     break;
    case areaC: for(y=1;y>2;y++)
                    circle(y);
                if(y=1)
                {
                    printf("the perimeter is %f",finish);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("the area is %f",finish);
                }
                break;
    case areaR:
    {
        square();
        printf("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    case areaS:
    {
        square();
        printf("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        printf("dont mess with me enter number between 1-6");
    }
}
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
/** why= to see what is the distance between any points\n
input=none
output=none
**/
int disBePoints(void)
{
float xOne=0,xTwo=0,yOne=0,yTwo=0, finish=0;
printf("Enter point 1 coordinates:");
scanf("%f%f",&xOne,&yOne);
printf("\nEnter point 2 coordinates:");
scanf("%f%f",&xTwo,&yTwo);
finish=sqrt(pow(xTwo-xOne,2)+pow(yTwo-yOne,2));
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is the hypotenuse of the triange
input=none
output=none
**/
int hypotri(void)
{
float x=0,y=0,finish;
printf("Enter 2 sides of the triangle:");
scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);
finish=sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2));
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is primeter and the area of the circle
input=none
output=none
**/
int circle(int y)
{
float radius=0,finish=0;
printf("Enter circle radius:");
scanf("%f",&radius);
if(y=1)
{
    finish=radius*2*Pi;
}
else
{
    finish=pow(radius,2)*Pi;
}
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is  the area of the rectangle or the square
input=none
output=none
**/
int square(void)
{
float yside=0,xside=0,finish=0;
printf("Enter  lentgh and width:");
scanf("%f%f",&xside,&yside);
finish=yside*xside;
return finish;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.141592
int hypotri(void);
int disBePoints(void);
int circle(int y);
int square(void);
enum calcOption
{
distance=1,
hypotenuse=2,
areaC=3,
areaR=4,
areaS=5
};


int main(void)
{
 int i=0;
float finish=0, y=0;
printf("Welcome to my calculator!\n");
while(i<1 || i>5 )
{
printf("Welcome to my calculator!\nchoose option:\n1 - Calc distance between 2 points\n2 - Calc hypotenuse of triangle\n3 - Calc area and perimeter of circle\n4 - Calc area of rectangle\n5 - Calc area of square\n6 - Exit");
scanf("%d",&i);
//calcOption option;
//option=calcOption(i);
switch(i)
{
    case distance: disBePoints();
                   printf("the distance is %f",finish);
                   break;

    case hypotenuse: hypotri();
                     printf("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
                     break;
    case areaC: for(y=1;y>2;y++)
                    circle(y);
                if(y=1)
                {
                    printf("the perimeter is %f",finish);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("the area is %f",finish);
                }
                break;
    case areaR:
    {
        square();
        printf("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    case areaS:
    {
        square();
        printf("the hypotenuse is %f",finish);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        printf("dont mess with me enter number between 1-6");
    }
}
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
/** why= to see what is the distance between any points\n
input=none
output=none
**/
int disBePoints(void)
{
float xOne=0,xTwo=0,yOne=0,yTwo=0, finish=0;
printf("Enter point 1 coordinates:");
scanf("%f%f",&xOne,&yOne);
printf("\nEnter point 2 coordinates:");
scanf("%f%f",&xTwo,&yTwo);
finish=sqrt(pow(xTwo-xOne,2)+pow(yTwo-yOne,2));
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is the hypotenuse of the triange
input=none
output=none
**/
int hypotri(void)
{
float x=0,y=0,finish;
printf("Enter 2 sides of the triangle:");
scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);
finish=sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2));
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is primeter and the area of the circle
input=none
output=none
**/
int circle(int y)
{
float radius=0,finish=0;
printf("Enter circle radius:");
scanf("%f",&radius);
if(y=1)
{
    finish=radius*2*Pi;
}
else
{
    finish=pow(radius,2)*Pi;
}
return finish;
}
/** why= to see what is  the area of the rectangle or the square
input=none
output=none
**/
int square(void)
{
float yside=0,xside=0,finish=0;
printf("Enter  lentgh and width:");
scanf("%f%f",&xside,&yside);
finish=yside*xside;
return finish;
}
```

**May I also know** why your various functions return type is int and you are returning float from the various functions and trying to print floating values.

I have done changes as my familiarity is with the ANSI-C standard.

Comment: @yarden if you feel satisfied then accept the answer and don't forget to vote up.